# Number of Average Concurrent and Peak Concurrent Users for a Web Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, web-applications, concurrency

I have a RoR 2.1 Web Application up and running on the Mongrel server and now i want to calculate the average number of concurrent users and peak concurrent users for the web application.

Is there an explicit way to figure this out or else what analytics should i use for calculating this?

The Back end of my application is MySQL and i tried looking for the values of `Threads_connected` and `Threads_created` in the Mysql Status. This values returns the number of currently open connections and the number of threads created to handle connections.

Does these value directly imply the number of currently connected users? If not please suggest ways of calculating these values.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL stats reflect on the number of processes connected to the database, so if you had 10 mongrels up you would probably see 10 there (plus whatever processes you had connected to the db ( scripts, daemons, console sessions etc)). This wouldn't change whether there were 100 users using the site or none (unless you have something scaling the number of processes)

In terms of number of users, google analytics can give a good idea of this sort of thing or analysing your own log files, depending on the level of sophistication you require.

Services like newrelic or union central are good if the end goal of this is figure out what server resources you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have as much concurrent users as you have mongrel processes, as Rails is single threaded unless you call **threadsafe** when configuring your app (but you should never do this unless you really understand the implications of doing so).

Comment: That's concurrent requests, which isn't entirely the same concurrent users.  If you had 1000 people, each loading a page every 30 seconds I would consider that to be 1000 concurrent users, but you could handle that with 10 mongrels (assuming each could do 3 requests/s)

Comment: Concurrent users assume there is information like average load time, average amount of requests users will make, none of this is available in the question and he's looking for threads on MySQL, so my guess was that he was looking for concurrent requests to his machine.

Comment: @FrederickCheung : So what can you suggest to get an approximate figure of number on concurrent users in the app. IS it same as that of the no. of mongrel processes? How can i get the count of mongrel processes at a given time?